# Is there any way to avoid evaluation of new subscriptions over existing entities?

Tags: fiware-orion

When I append a new subscription in ORION, it automatically evaluates the condition and it invoques the designed end-point for that. I want that the new subscription affects only entities appended later.

Is there any way to avoid it or I have to control this at end-point level?

Related to this, is there any batch option to create several subscriptions at same time for a initial load of the platform?

Orion Version: 1.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Regarding initial notification:*

No, it isn't.

We understand that for some uses cases this is not convenient. However, behaving in the opossite way ruins another uses cases which need to know the "inicial state" before starting getting notifications corresponding to actual changes. The best solution to make everybody happy is to make this configurable, so each client can chose what it prefers. This feature is currently in our roadmap (see [this issue in github.com](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/920)).

While this gets implemented in Orion, in your case maybe a possible workaround is just ignore the first received nofitication belonging to a subscription (you can identify the subscription to which one notification belongs by the `subscriptionId` field in the notification payload). All the following notifications beloning to that subscription will correspond to actual changes.

*Regarding batch option to create several subscriptions*

No, there isn't any operation like that.

**EDIT:** the posibility of avoiding initial notification has been finally implemented at Orion. Details are at [this section of the documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/initial_notification/index.html#avoid-initial-notification). It is now in the master branch (so if you use `fiware/orion:latest` docker you will get it) and will be include in next Orion version (2.2.0).

Comment: If you are interested in the feature described in https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/920 please show your support adding a "+1" comment to it. It is importand for us the users feedback about which features they find interesting.

Comment: Answer has been edited to include relevant information related initial notification skiping.